# Iniciante - Dificuldade em imprimir datas em Python

Tags: python, datetime

Sou iniciante em programação, e estou começando em python.
Gostaria de calcular a diferença de dias de um contrato. Mas estou com dificuldade em imprimir essa informação.

```
from datetime import date
from msilib.schema import Class

class dados_servidor:
    def __init__(self, cpf, nome, adm, cargo, sit_fun):
        self.nome = nome
        self.masp = cpf
        self.adm = adm
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.sit_fun = sit_fun
        self.data_ini = 23,7,2022
        self.data_fim = 24,7,2022
        
    
    def contagem_de_dias(self):
        return (self.data_ini - self.data_fim).days

    mateus = dados_servidor('00.0.0.000', 'Mateus Carlos Sampaio', '1', 'Professor', 'Designado' )

print (dados_servidor.contagem_de_dias(mateus))
print (mateus.contagem_de_dias)

def __str__(self):
       return f'Nome: {self.nome} Masp: {self.masp} ADM: {self.adm} Cargo: {self.cargo} Situação Fun: {self.sit_fun} Data inicial: {self.data_ini} Data Fim: {self.data_fim}  '
```

Answer (score -1):

Para comparar datas você precisa utilizar o pacote de `datetime` ou algum pacote relacionado à datas, no seu código você esta utilizando uma `Tuple` nos campos `data_ini` e `data_fim`

```
from datetime import datetime

self.data_ini = datetime(2022, 7, 23)
self.data_fim = datetime(2022, 7, 24)

def contagem_de_dias(self):
    return (self.data_fim - self.data_ini).days
```

Aprenda mais sobre tuplas: https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/conhecendo-as-tuplas-no-python

Aprenda mais sobre datas: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp